# Spring annotations : setting @sessionAttributes in @component class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

Is it possible to set a session attribute in a manager class (class which is not a controller and is marked as @component)?
    The scenario is like this, from my Controller i'm calling a manager class which does some logic. I want to store the result of this logic in the session, so that i can use it in the later requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `@SessionAttribute` is a controller-specific concept. To get similar behaviour in other components you can use [session-scoped beans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other).